# How to use ncurses to take integer as a variable?

Tags: c, curses

I am using curses and trying to take integers as input from the user. what command I should use as getch() takes input from the user but it is a character.

Comment: `getch()` takes the input as soon as you enter the character, but how would that work for integers with many digits? I don't think it would know when to stop. Also, if it's a one-digit number you want, you can just minus the inputted character by `'0'`

Comment: Use [`scanw`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanw.3x.html) and friends?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code yet, but you should be able to scan for multiple characters using `getch()`, store them in a string and then convert the string to an integer using [`strtoimax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoimax) from `<inttypes.h>`.

```
char str[10];
str[0] = getch();
for (int i = 1; str[i - 1] != '\n' && i < 9; ++i)
    str[i] = getch();
str[9] = '\0';

char *endp;
int n = strtoimax(str, &endp, 10));
```

Comment: Let me know if it works, because I haven't tested the code.